# Why am I getting invalid hook call error in HOC

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-functions

when I try to put the useState inside the WithCounter which is an HOC function, it shows an error in the console.

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

but if I put the useState inside the Render function instead of WithCounter , it works perfectly fine.
please let me know the technical details for the above problem.

below is the code which gives the error

```
import { useState } from 'react'


const WithCounter = (EnhancedCounter) => {

    const [count, setCount] = useState({
        number: 0,
        name: 'charitha'
    });

    const Render = () => {

        const handleClick = () => {

            setCount((prev) => ({
                number: prev.number + 1,
                name: 'sanjana'
            }))
            console.log(count.number, count.name)
        }

        return (
            <EnhancedCounter handleClick={handleClick} count={count.number} name={count.name} />
        )
    }

    return Render

}

export default WithCounter
```

please tell me know the technical details for the above and what rules of hooks it violates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to execute your `Render` function?

```js
const WithCounter = (EnhancedCounter) => {
    // ... your code
    return Render()

}
```

But tbh, I don't understand why WithCounter component should have EnhancedCounter state.

Comment: WithCounter is higher order component which receives EnhancedCounter component as a parameter. in ther Render function, EnhancedCounter component is modified and returned. what my problem is, if I try to include the useState inside the Render function, it works fine. but not when I put it inside the WithCounter as in the code in the post.